# Infinite series manipulation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, generating-functions

I have the series

$$T(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t_nx^n$$

Is there anyway to express $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nt_nx^n$ in terms of $T(x)$? I tried differentiating $T(x)$ but only got so far as to express the latter as $xT'(x)$.

If that desired form of $T(x)$ is not possible, then is there a way to solve the following for $T(x)$?
$$x^2T'(x) +(3x-1)T(x) +1 = 0$$
My goal is to obtain an algebraic expression for $T(x)$, preferably one that could be then manipulated to obtain an infinite power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n t_n x^n = x T'(x)$$.

$$ x^2 T'(x) + (3x-1) T(x) + 1 = 0$$
is a first-order linear differential equation.  Its general solution is
$$
c \frac{\exp(-1/x)}{x^3} - \frac{\exp(-1/x) \Gamma(0,-1/x)}{2 x^3} - \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{2x^3}
$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.  However, this is not analytic at $x=0$.

EDIT: In terms of the $t_n$, your differential equation says
$t_0 = 1$ and $t_n = (n+2) t_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 1$.  This recurrence can easily be solved, to obtain $t_n = (n+2)!/2$.  However, the series 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)!\; x^n/2$ diverges for all $x \ne 0$.